# Plotting dataframe for each row pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I need one plot that collect one single line plot for each row over all columns except the first column that appear as a legend to identify each line plot. This is the for loop I wrote.

```
for i in range(0,5):
    plt.plot(df.iloc[i, 1:], label=df.iloc[i,0])
    plt.legend()
```

However in this way the y-axis is messed-up[image: as seen in the picture below, this messes up also the plot that are not correct]

Comment: Is your data string valued?

Comment: no, they are float

Comment: btw, you can do `df.set_index(df.columns[0]).T.plot()`